# How to read particular key value data from dictionary using python

Tags: python

I have a file from which I need to extract the particular dictionary value

Data is in below format in file:

```
{'name': 'xyz', 'age': 14, 'country': 'india'}
```

My code:

```
var = 'country'
with open('abc.txt', 'r') as fw:
    first_line = fw.readline()
    dictvalue = first_line[var]
    print(dictvalue)
```

But this is not fetching value : `india`, it is throwing error: `string indices must be integer`

Comment: Because file is always read as string..

Comment: @ThePyGuy how to achieve it any idea ?

Comment: The data in your file is a *string*, not a dictionary. Is it maybe supposed to be JSON? If it is, you will need to fix the quoting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `first_line=fw.readline()` returns `string`, not `dict`. You can convert string to dict, using `ast` module:

```
import ast

var='country'
with open('abc.txt','r') as fw:
    first_line=fw.readline()
    dictvalue= ast.literal_eval(first_line)[var]
    print(dictvalue)
```

Also you would need to format your file, because `india` should be in within single quote

```
{'name': 'xyz','age': 14,'country': 'india'}
```

Output:

```
india
```

[Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/988228/15777370)

Answer (score 1):

in this line of code,

```
first_line=fw.readline()
```

`first_line` is read as string ie., `"{'name':'xyz','age':14,'country':'india'}"`

**Solution 1:**
You can make use of [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

```
mydict = eval(first_line)
print(mydict[var])
#'india'
```

This works, but you should avoid using [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) and [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) functions, because it is considered as "dangerous" function in python. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) for more on this topic.

**Solution 2 (Recommended):**
Use [Json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to read/write dict objects.

```
 import json
 data = {'name':'xyz','age':14,'country':'india'}

 #save dict as 'abc.txt' file. alternately use 'abc.json' to save as JSON file.
 json.dump(data, open('abc.txt','w'))

read_data = json.load(open('abc.txt', 'r'))
print (read_data)
#{'name': 'xyz', 'age': 14, 'country': 'india'}
```